# Mineflayer-pathfinder goto coordinates

Tags: javascript, minecraft, path-finding, mineflayer

I want to program that I can enter coordinates in the Minecraft chat and the bot will go to them. But I don't know how to program something like that? Can anyone help?

I am new to this field and would like to test something simple, but I just can't do it.

This is the code I try to use but it wont work:

```
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, GoalBlock } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const pathfinder = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').pathfinder
const Movements = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').Movements
const { GoalNear } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').goals
const inventoryViewer = require('mineflayer-web-inventory')

var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: "localhost",   
  username: "MLGPlayer9",
  version: "1.18.1"
})

inventoryViewer(bot)

bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)

function greeting() {
  bot.chat("Mooooooin");
}

bot.once("spawn", greeting);
 
function goto() {
  bot.pathfinder.goto(1, 1, 1);
  
}

bot.once("spawn", goto);
```

Answer (score 0):

bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(1, 1, 1, 1))
The last one is for how close

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).